# Cufon script not working with opencart installation

Tags: javascript, jquery, cufon, opencart

This Cufon script was working perfectly for me on another site, so this is frustrating. :/ Can you spot anything wrong? The pieces of code are located just before the ending head tag and just after the opening body tag.

The cufon and font .js files are both fine and in the right directory.

code: view-source:http://www.stephaniehenderson.com/mmsecret/

Comment: Looks to be working now Stephanie. Did you solve this?

Comment: Yes, just a few hours ago today. Thanks for looking.